# Caching and common Workflow with Typo3 Extension development

Tags: caching, typo3, fluid, extbase

I am developing my first typo3 extension with Extbase and Fluid.
Whenever I change something in any PHP file (a controller for example) I have to deactivate and reactivate my extension to see the changes.
That costs a lot of time and is really annoying..

Flushing the caches didn't solve the problem for me.

How can I speed up my typo3 extension development workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the caches from the install tool, that also flushes the caches that contain annotation data.

To ease the process of doing so, you could check out the extension [`typo3_console`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3_console), it should contain a command to flush the caches from the command line. Although I have never used it myself, I've heard many good things about it.